# Can we serialize the updated object in Scala?

Tags: scala, object, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to serialize the updated values for an object in Scala. Although the serialized file shows the updated string but when I deserialize it I am getting the initial values not the updated one.

```
import java.io._
object AnObject extends Serializable
{
    var x = 2.0
    var s = "Here's a string"

} // AnObject object


object ObjectSerialization extends App
{
    AnObject.s = "This is an updated string"
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream ("src/AnObject.ser"))
    oos.writeObject (AnObject)
    oos.close ()
} // ObjectDeserialization object

object ObjectDeserialization extends App {
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("src/AnObject.ser"))
    val obj = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[AnObject.type]
    ois.close

    println(obj.s)
}
```

I am expecting output "This is an updated string". Kindly let me know if you have any idea. Thanks

Comment: A singleton mutable object which is going to be serliazed as some state smells like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`object` creates a singleton, you can't simply serialize and deserialize multiple instances of a singleton. Try the same with a `class` instead of `object`, this should work

Comment: Even if the object is singleton but it is mutable

Comment: Actually I want to store number of times the class is called. For that I need to store value in object as companion object of class. So, using class won't work

Comment: Only object can store values for multiple class instances.

Comment: @QuickSilver it makes no sense to deserialize a mutable singleton though, for most applications. Serialization is for storing and/or exchanging data. You're typically going to serialize or deserialize instances of the same model (we can call it a class in OO languages) in the lifetime of the application. Deserialize a singleton makes little sense to me. What you might want to do is initialize a singleton from data contained in a file, but I would do it lazily, only once, and the output would be immutable. Seems much safer than a mutable singleton...

Comment: @helooworld then you should probably rephrase your question to state exactly what you want to do. But whatever it is, the answer is most likely not going to be that you need to have a mutable singleton

Comment: I want to store object into file and use that data rebuild that object with updated values. Because in Scala we can only use variable in objects as static member. I don't want to loose values using class instances.

Comment: But if you really want to do that, why don't you simply store the values in a CSV or JSON and then set them back? You cannot instantiate a singleton twice, there's no chance you will be able to deserialize it and automatically update its values. I still don't know why you want to do this but I have to tell you this is not idiomatic Scala